# Splunk pods are going into Crashloopbackoff

Tags: kubernetes-helm, splunk

I have installed "splunk-connect-for-kubernetes" helm chart from https://github.com/splunk/splunk-connect-for-kubernetes/ but in my case some of the pods are going into carshloopbackoff with below error logs.

Can someone help me here.

```
NAME                                     READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE   IP                NODE                NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
lv-splunk-logging-5q9pf                  0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   12         47m   192.168.54.241    las2-m***31        <none>           <none>
lv-splunk-logging-nzzld                  0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   13         47m   192.168.97.152    las2-m***18        <none>           <none>
lv-splunk-logging-qjfgw                  0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   13         47m   192.168.178.41    aws-m****03         <none>           <none>
lv-splunk-logging-zmvxp                  0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   13         47m   192.168.11.174    las2-***11        <none>           <none>
```

kubectl logs

```
2023-02-06 14:42:08 +0000 [info]: init supervisor logger path=nil rotate_age=nil rotate_size=nil
2023-02-06 14:42:08 +0000 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf"
2023-02-06 14:42:08 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.15.3'
2023-02-06 14:42:08 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-concat' version '2.4.0'
2023-02-06 14:42:08 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-jq' version '0.5.1'
2023-02-06 14:42:08 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter' version '3.1.0'
2023-02-06 14:42:08 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-prometheus' version '2.0.2'
2023-02-06 14:42:08 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-record-modifier' version '2.1.0'
2023-02-06 14:42:08 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-splunk-hec' version '1.3.1'
2023-02-06 14:42:08 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-systemd' version '1.0.2'
2023-02-06 14:42:08 +0000 [INFO]: Reading bearer token from /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
2023-02-06 14:42:11 +0000 [error]: config error file="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf" error_class=Fluent::ConfigError error="Invalid Kubernetes API v1 endpoint https://10.96.0.1:443/api: Timed out connecting to server"
```

All pods are up and running.`your text`

Comment: What version of kubernetes are you running?

Comment: Hi SiHa , its version 1.17

Comment: Ah, OK. There's a change in 1.24+ where there is no default secret, I thought it may be connected, but obviously not.